# Is the GRE experimental section randomly assigned or influenced by program of study?

Tags: gre

I heard a rumor on a message board stating that the experimental section of the GRE is influenced by whatever the test-taker chooses as a field of study e.g. the test would add a Verbal section for Literature majors, or Quant for engineering majors.

Is this true? Or is the experimental section truly random for all test-takers?

Thank you

Comment: I think they would randomly include experimental questions. They need to know how the question works for all fields-of-study.

Comment: It does not benefit the GRE to be given to those that would likely do better at the section, as that reduces score disparity. If anything, it'd be more likely for it to be the opposite to ensure that hard questions are sufficiently hard. That being said, it is likely true random, similar to how it was done in the olden days with paper booklets, for sanity purposes.